# Flavor error duplicate classes after updating to Gradle 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio and Gradle to version 3.0 I can't build my app with 3 flavors (dbg, production, and nostore production)
In java/src folder of each flavor source set (exclude main) I have class *Flavors.class* with some methods specified for this source set.
But when I try to Run or Build app I have error:
`Error:(9, 8) error: duplicate class: my.app.namespace.Flavors`.
Also I add to Gradle variant dimensions `flavorDimensions "dbg", "prod","nostore"` and add `dimension` value to each flavor section.
This is how its look:

```
android{
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
   ...
   flavorDimensions "dbg", "prod","nostore"
   productFlavors {

    dbg{
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        }
        dimension "dbg"
    }

    production{
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        }
        dimension "prod"
    }

    nostoreprod {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        }
        dimension "nostore"
    }
  }     
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong, this code look like in samples on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html.
And one thing, on Build Variants panel now I have only 2 variants: `dbgProductionNostoreprodDebug` and `dbgProductionNostoreprodRelease` but in previous version of AS and Gradle I had different variants for each flavor on this panel. (Look like AStudio try to make single build with all variants in same time or what?)

Comment: You probably should not name your flavour and your flavour dimensions the same. See more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors). You probably need only one dimension.

Comment: clean project, and rebuild: it could go through on my system. I did see only one dimension is available to build, investigating.  not very relative, if ABIs are all same, you could do it with: defaultConfig.ndk.abiFilters "armeabi", "x86" ( to save some typing ).  With this PR https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/pull/445, will find out more.

Comment: @Eselfar thank you. It's right, i left only one dimension and now can run my app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The configuration you pasted will correctly produce only 2 variants, because each of the 3 dimension only has 1 flavor and then there are 2 implicit build types (release and debug):

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
| dbg |    prod    |   nostore   | buildType |        resulting variant        |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
| dbg | production | nostoreprod | debug     | dbgProductionNostoreprodDebug   |
| dbg | production | nostoreprod | release   | dbgProductionNostoreprodRelease |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
```

What you probably wanted is 1 flavor dimension with 3 flavors instead:

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| myDimensionName | buildType | resulting variant  |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| dbg             | debug     | dbgDebug           |
| dbg             | release   | dbgRelease         |
| production      | debug     | prodDebug          |
| production      | release   | prodRelease        |
| nostoreprod     | debug     | nostoreprodDebug   |
| nostoreprod     | release   | nostoreprodRelease |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Which could look like this:

```
...
flavorDimensions "myDimensionName"
productFlavors {

dbg{
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
    }
    dimension "myDimensionName"
}

production{
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
    }
    dimension "myDimensionName"
}

nostoreprod {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
    }
    dimension "myDimensionName"
}
```